# Are physical dualities based on mathematical dualities?

Tags: terminology, definition, mathematics, duality

I understand what a physical duality is and what a mathematical duality is. The function to obtain the dual of an theory/object is an invertible function in both physics and math. I wonder if it is as easy to derive a physical duality as it is to derive a mathematical duality.

A duality in physics is more or less a pair of theories. Sometimes either one can be used to make correct predictions on its own, and other times a specific side of the duality must be used to obtain correct predictions. Often the one where calculations are more convenient is used.

On the other hand, a duality in mathematics appears to be more rigorously defined. In math, one can derive the dual of an object without the memorization required in physics. For example the dual of a category can be obtained by switching around the direction of its arrows.

It would make physics much more convenient if I could be shown a function that takes a physical theory to its dual. Does the word "dual" in physics mean the same thing as it means in mathematics? How does one systematically obtain the dual of a physical theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the word duality used in physics for wave particle duality, bra-ket duality, dual four vectors, and Hodge duality.

The first one is probably just the english usage of the word "duality". It means particles have wavefunctions associated with them.

The other three are mathematical dualities, as in, they allow you to take a mathematical object : a bra, a four vector or a Differential form, and get a unique dual mathematical object : a ket, a dual vector, or the Hodge dual

> It would make physics much more convenient if I could be shown a function that takes a physical theory to its dual.

There can be no such general function because duality is an extremely broad term.

One example of a duality can be when you change the mathematical framework of Quantum Mechanics from Hilbert space to Phase space. The [Wigner-Weyl transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Weyl_transform) is used to switch between operators and functions.